# Нарушение прав доступа при чтении

Tags: c++, dll

Есть библиотека со статической линковкой (исходников нет) и файлы заголовков для С++. Мне нужно сделать из неё библиотеку с динамической линковкой.

Сделал динамическую библиотеку с экспортом функций.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "rtl2.lib")    
D3RTL_API msp_ERROR sp_Startup(void);

D3RTL_API msp_ERROR sp_Startup()
{
    return msp_Startup(); // Вот тут возникает ошибка
}
```

Создал консольное приложение с динамическим подключением библиотеки.

```
typedef msp_ERROR (*TESTFUNCTION)(void);

DWORD err;
HINSTANCE hDll = LoadLibrary(L"F:\\Projects\\msp\\Debug\\msp.dll");
if (hDll != NULL)
{
    printf("Library was loaded\n");
}
else
{
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("Couldn't load dll. Error code %d\n", err);
    return -1;
}
// получение указателя на функцию библиотеки
TESTFUNCTION lpTestFunction = (TESTFUNCTION)GetProcAddress(hDll, "?sp_Startup@@YAHXZ");
if (lpTestFunction != NULL)
{
    msp_ERROR e = lpTestFunction();
    cout << "error = " << e << endl;
}
// освобождение дескриптора
FreeLibrary(hDll);    
return 0;
```

Дома проект под Win 7 и MS VC 2012 работает, а на работе Win XP MS VC 2010 не работает. Выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> Необработанное исключение в
> "0x1001c462 (msp.dll)" в "test.exe":
> 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при
> чтении "0x00000000".

При этом, если в консольном приложении подключить статическую библиотеку msp.lib (без динамической), то всё работает.

Посему два вопроса:

1. Может, можно из статической в динамическую библиотеку проще преобразовать?
2. Как исправить ошибку?